# TestCaseDesign Tab is Missing in window list #aTosca

Tags: tosca

I closed the TestCaseDesign tab in tosc, now I am not able to open this tab as it is not showing in windows list. Could anyone help me?

I tried to find this in PROJECT->Options/settings, but did not get anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhlxi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Successfully, I found TestCaseDesign tab under Home-> Section -> TestCaseDesign.

Thanks, who marked this question as not useful.

[Please find this Image as reference, you will understand what was the matter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyETN.png)